# JAVA Whats the easiest way to transform Hashmap<String, array> to a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a hashmap of  Array size is always constant so they are all of the same. How would transform this into 2d array?

example

```
key1 -> [1,2,3]
key2 -> [2,3,3]
key3 -> [4,3,6]
key4 -> [5,6,2]
```

I want the 2d array to be like

```
[1,2,3]

[2,3,3]

[4,3,6]

[5,6,2]
```

Comment: Why do you have a `HashMap<String, int[]>` in the first place?

Comment: @PaulBoddington I needed a key, value data structures so i have it

Comment: If the keys are `key1`, `key2`, `key3`, `key4` it makes much more sense to use a `List` or an array.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I'm new so I m not sure but keys are different... this was just an example

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
map.values().toArray(new int[map.size()][]);
```

Alternatively, if you are using Java 8, you can use:

```
map.values().stream().toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Here is an example program.

```
Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("First", new int[] {1, 2, 3});
map.put("Second", new int[] {4, 5, 6});
map.put("Third", new int[] {7, 8, 9});
int[][] array = map.values().toArray(new int[map.size()][]);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

This program prints

```
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Notice that it has changed the order. If you want the order of the rows to be the same as the order you put the arrays into the map you can use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
public int[] to2dArray(Map<String, int[]> map)
{
    int[][] out = new int[map.size()][];
    int index = 0;
    for (int[] i : map.values()) 
    {
        out[index] = i;
        index++;
    }
    return out;
```

As a general hint, you may want to reconsider what kind of `Map` you use. You use a `HashMap`, which is unordered, so the order that the 2D array is in may vary.